# Postgresql: Why incremental size is negative at barman backup details?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, barman

Here my backup method is rsync and reuse_backup=link. Everything doing well, but why incremental size showing negative value. Necessary details given below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the negative percentage showing the relative size of the incremental backup, in relation to the disk usage?

In your case 112.4 MiB is 21.3% smaller than 142.9 MiB.